# What is the easiest way to quickly generate an image from TeX source?

Tags: graphics

Often one wants to quickly generate an image from a small piece of TeX. (E.g. for inclusion in a question here.) What's the quickest way of doing it?

Comment: Duplicate: [TeX to image over command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line/)

Comment: Hmm. The answers that don't mention mathurl, and adding it in an answer seems inappropriate (since it's not a commandline tool). Also, for those of us on Windows, commandline is relatively awkward.

Comment: I'd say that the question Peter links to should be edited to be more general so that mathurl *is* an answer to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://mathurl.com/ generates PNGs.

Comment: Credit to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/what-useful-web-services-are-out-there for the pointer. (It took a lot of searching to find, and lacked the [graphics] tag, so I created a more specific question.)

Answer (score 3):

The `standalone` package produces documents with a page size cropped to the text so the resulting pdf can be directly used as the image file in some circumstances. Search this site for `standalone` and you'll see it used in many examples.

What I usually do for images for answers posted here (on windows) is I just run the example and preview in acrobat or xpdf or whatever and then use the print screen key and paste it into paint or some other editor and manually crop. That way I can crop to the part that is relevant to the answer rather than the full text of lipsum blah blahh that often gets used in examples.