# I want to write Maths on my computer just as I write maths on my copy or register. What should I do?

Tags: math-mode, tools

I want to write Maths on my computer just as I write maths on my copy or register. What should I do? I want to write Maths, should I buy a Graphic tablet (digitizer) Or something else?

Comment: Hi!. Your question is off-topic. Questions on TeX.SX are expected to generally relate to TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: I flagged this question for migration to [SU].

Comment: The question does not mention TeX, but we surely thought about the exact same problem here before with suprising answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr