# Is there a software to LaTeX a hand written equation?

Tags: conversion

Typing equations in LaTeX takes time and I was wondering if there is a software that converts a handwritten equation (on a tablet or a scanned paper) into typed equation in LaTeX

Does such a software exist?

Comment: If you are using windows, try inlage: http://www.inlage.com/. It can recognise some thing like that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I would be surprised if there was something less time-consuming which could do this. Especially since OCR is not very good at hand-written text, never mind maths! @HarishKumar Is that for whole equations or just characters? (I couldn't tell much from the description.)

Comment: @cfr You can do whole equations!

Comment: @HarishKumar And it works?

Comment: And there is http://www.inftyproject.org/en/software.html#InftyReader.

Comment: @cfr What do you mean? I never use it but it should work.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr?rq=1

Comment: @HarishKumar My impression of OCR has generally been that it is getting to be not bad for printed stuff - text, at least, but maybe maths too. But that handwriting is still a big unknown. Of course, I dare say it depends on your writing, too. But I'd expect to spend a lot of time checking for errors etc. I just doubt the status of *any* solution here as a way to speed things up.

Comment: @cfr I agree with you on this point. handwriting is more suitable for hand held devices like tablets. And I am very bad in that too. :-)

Comment: @cfr: here: [Possible to Convert Math in Picture into LaTeX? How?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155231)