# Is is possible to convert an image to a tex formula? (Free vs paid)

Tags: math-mode, tools, latex-base

Is it possible to convert an image to a tex formula? I would like to know free and paid solutions (which of them free and which of them paid).

Thank you!

Comment: You can try this here: https://mathpix.com

Comment: Also try with `Infty Reader`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to Convert Math in Picture into LaTeX? How?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/possible-to-convert-math-in-picture-into-latex-how)

Comment: Also of interest may be [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8503/) or [What is the status of generating LaTeX from handwriting (i.e., OCR)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1443/)