# Converting Handwriting to LaTeX Plaincode

Tags: conversion

*Is it possible to write LaTeX code using handwriting on, say, an Ipad. Do you have any practical tips in setting that up.*

This question is similar to:[This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr). That question wants to start from a "compiled document", where the handwriting is suppossed to be replicated in the final compiled document. I am asking something simpler. I just want to be able to write the code for LaTeX (and preferably operating the compiling as well), without using a keyboard, and using my pen instead.

Comment: There is no iOS app that compiles LaTeX code and at the same time has a full handwriting-OCR based editor... There are apps for both of those separate needs, though, and you could just switch between them, copy-pasting. You'll likely have more luck setting up a smooth workflow on a computer, like a handwriting-OCR overlay while using a LaTeX editor for example...? But setting up handwriting recognition or how to send text from one application to another is probably off-topic for TeX.SE.

Comment: Even if possible, debug handwritting code interpreted by an OCR could be a nightmare, some kind of chinese torture...