# How do I generate LaTeX code faster?

Tags: math-mode

I am a new member on stack exchange and I find it very tedious to write codes for mathematical equations in order to ask and answer questions. Is there a shorter and quicker way (with help from some websites and applications) to do that for free?

Comment: Mathpix (https://mathpix.com/), maybe? However, its trial version limits to 50 scans, more or less.

Comment: Also, possible duplicate: 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speeding up LaTeX compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation)

Comment: @AndréC: Are you sure, the question you suggest is a duplicate? As far as I understood this question, the OP is interested in learning how to produce LaTeX code faster, while the question you linked to deals with decreasing the time needed to compile such a code.

Comment: @leandriis Chances are you understood better than I did, I retracted my vote.

Comment: @Shriom My nephew wrote his thesis with [LyX – The Document Processor](https://www.lyx.org), he says that to write complicated and convoluted equations of fluid mechanics, it saved him a lot of time.

Comment: @AndréC the OP wants to type math formula in stackexchange sites with mathjax, lyx won't help much

Comment: there is no reason really why typing mathjax expressions should be slower than typing the markdown for the rest of the post, but stackexchange sites don't use tex, so it's not really an on-topic question here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Decidedly, I really didn't understand his question.