# typewritten to Latex

Tags: typewriter

I have a math book from the '60s in PDF. It's typewritten and I found it harder to read than a Latex edition, but couldn't find any modern edition.

Is there an app or site or some way to transform it to Latex? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might start by running it through [one of these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr)

Comment: Thanks! For what I've seen, those apps are for scanning and texifying snippets of handwritten text. I want to scan a whole book written with typewriter. (Sorry for my english!)

Comment: Your English is fine, don’t worry. You can try it and see if it works. At the very least, it greatly reduce the amount of editing you would have to do by hand.

Comment: For the plain text, check  if you can copy and paste text or if `pdftotext` or `pdftohtml`  are able to produce some output. Otherwise, you can use an OCR. Then you can convert the output in .txt., .docx, .html, etc. to LaTeX with `pandoc` or similar tools., Anyway if the scanned pages have a poor quality, you will finish earlier writing the book yourself.

Comment: What is the title of the book? Maybe somebody here knows if there is a modern edition available, or some kind of source of the original text.